# neural network word grouping using deeplearning4j

Tags: java, word2vec, deeplearning4j

i am working on neural network (java, deeplearning4j), that will classify the words. For example i will have 3 groups: sport, music, science. I check topics, tutorials and examples. The problem is: what is the best way to do it?

That is what i tried:
1) text file like this:
       football, 0
       bass, 1
       aircraft, 2 ....
   Than i create a CSVRecordReader ... but it crashed because it is a text.
2) Create Word2Vec with words, but i don't know how to label it to get suitable groups.

Could you please advise? Thank you in advance